# How can I get the new URL, old URL and transition type when navigating?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension which triggers when a navigation occurs. I'm using the `onComitted` event for that, but I can't seem to find a way to get the previous URL of the tab.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(data) {
    transitionType = data.transitionType;
    newUrl = data.url;
    oldUrl = ?
});
```

What I've tried so far:

- Getting the URL of the tab with id `data.tabId`, but its URL seems to be identical to `data.url` (i.e. already updated).
- Using `onBeforeNavigate` instead of `onComitted`, but I could not find the old URL there, plus that event does not have the transition type.
- Sticking with `onComitted` and just getting the previous URL of the current tab, but I could not find any way to do that.

How can I get all three pieces of information from each navigation?

Comment: I've also tried to ask a simpler, related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229422/how-can-i-get-the-previous-url-of-a-tab. Maybe an answer there will help steer me toward a solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. Basically I follow [the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25241421/242762) to find the previous URL of a tab, and I perform that retrieval also on `onComitted`, where I can find the new URL and the transition type.