# How can I get the previous URL of a tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When writing a Chrome extension, given a tab, how can I get the URL of the previously-visited page in that tab? i.e. the url that will appear in the omnibar after I hit "back"?

Comment: Would `window.history.back()` be sufficient?

Comment: @DavidSawyer but that would change the tab in which the extension is running, not the tab which I'm targeting, unless you suggest I inject it into that tab. And in any case this changes the tab, not just returns the previous url.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not sure what would be best, then.

Comment: you probably need to maintain your own list of visited tabs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I could not find any API approach, I just applied [vux777's suggestion above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229422/how-can-i-get-the-previous-url-of-a-tab#comment39307506_25229422): every time a page loads I store a mapping from its id to its URL. Then when I want to find the previous page of a tab, I can search for it there.

So, storage:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function (data) {
  if (data.frameId !== 0) {
      // Don't trigger on iframes
      return;
  }

  var tabIdToUrl = {};
  tabIdToUrl[data.tabId.toString()] = data.url;
  chrome.storage.local.set(tabIdToUrl);
});
```

And retrieval:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(tabId, function (item) {
  var url = item[tabId];
  ...
});
```

Comment: This is asynchronous; since it is possible that you don't need persistent storage of this information, maybe it's better to implement a synchronous in-memory storage.

Comment: @Xan that's a good point, would you mind editing my answer (or adding a new one) to show how to do that?

Comment: No special tricks - unless you're using an Event page that gets unloaded, you can keep the `tabIdToUrl` object global in your background page. It will live as long as your background page is active.

Comment: @Xan ah, but my background is `"persistent": false`, which I guess would cause a problem here.

Comment: Yes, then `chrome.storage` is the best solution. You can also use `localStorage`, it's old-fashioned but persistent and synchronous.

Comment: Is this in your content script or the background page? If you could provide some more explanation of what code goes where, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

I am running into the same issue, really wished that chrome api could return both the before and after url at [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) event.

My solution is similar to @Oak, but instead of using [`chrome.storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-local) I am using [`Window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) due to the following two reasons:

1. `chrome.storage.local` behaves similarly to `Window.localStorage`, **it persists even when the browser is closed and reopened**. If you don't do cleanup yourself, your local storage will grow overtime with a lot of redundant information. With session storage, whenever you closed all of your browser instances (end of persistent background page's lifetime). it will conveniently forget everything :)
2. `Window.sessionStorage` stores data in **strings only**, which is good for this use case (**tab.url**), `chrome.storage.local` is a more powerful tool, you can save some space when you want to store objects.

my test case is something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
    var newUrl = changeInfo.url;
    if(newUrl){
        window.sessionStorage[tabId] = newUrl;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach uses the [referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) of the page. This requires that:

- there must be some way to retrieve the page referrer, either by loading a content script into the page that communicates the referrer to the extension, or by somehow inspecting the web navigation or request as it is happening in the background script to retrieve the `Referer` header (notice the typo)
- the page that referred to the current page must have a [referrer policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) that provides sufficient information

`content-script.js`

```
// notify extension that a page has loaded its content script, and send referrer
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ referrer: document.referrer });
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(sender.tab.id);
  console.log(request.referrer);
});
```

Alternatively, the extension could query a tab to get its referrer. You must ensure the tab is ready (has a loaded content script):

`content-script.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse({ referrer: document.referrer });
});
```

`background.js`

```
function askTabForReferrer(tabId) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.referrer);
  });
}

const exisitingTabWithLoadedContentScriptId = 83;
askTabForReferrer(exisitingTabWithLoadedContentScriptId);
```

Comment: but this does not include checking if it's the same tab, does it?!